# Visual Studio Code: excluding paths from search

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I exclude a workspace-relative path from all searches in Visual Studio Code, regardless of what I type into "Files to include"?

In the Search panel, I have the "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files" button selected. And my user settings, I have:

```
"search.exclude": {
    "foo/bar/baz/**/*": true
},
```

When I search with "Files to include" empty, it ignores these files. But when I put anything in "Files to include", like `./foo`, they appear in the results.